# new bool** matrix vs new bool*matrix vs new bool matrix different types of cpp initialization confusion?

Tags: c++, matrix, data-structures

So,far after doing my own research i know bool** matrix will create 2d array,bool* matrix will create 1d array. Now,when implementing graphs using adjacency matrix

```
 private:
  bool** adjMatrix;
  int numVertices;

   public:
  Graph(int numVertices) {
    this->numVertices = numVertices;
    adjMatrix = new bool*[numVertices];//<---here
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
      adjMatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];//<--here
      for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
        adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
```

Now, i commented the part where i am confused, see both lines look similar to me as per my above mentioned understanding.

Comment: The general syntax for allocating an array is `new T[size]`. On the first line, `T=bool*`, on the second `T=bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new bool*[numVertices]` allocates and constructs an array of `bool*` (pointer to `bool`) of length `numVertices`. `new bool[numVertices]` allocates and constructs an array of `bool` of length `numVertices`.

What your code is doing is:

- Declaring `adjMatrix` as a pointer to a pointer to `bool`
- Setting `adjMatrix` to point to the first element of an array of `bool*`
- Setting each element of that array to point to the first element of an array of `bool`

This gives the effect of `adjMatrix` looking like a 2D array, since you can write `adjMatrix[i][j]` and access one of the `bool` elements. However, this setup is not ideal for a few reasons.

- It takes two pointer derefs to reach an array element rather than one
- You have to do `numVertices+1` dynamic allocations
- The calls to `new bool[numVertices]` are not guaranteed to put all of the `bool`s next to each other in memory

It would be better to make `adjMatrix` just be a `bool*`, and allocate all the bools at once:

```
adjMatrix = new bool[numVertices * numVertices];
```

This will save you `numVertices` dynamic allocations and put all the bools in a contiguous block of memory (better for cache). You could then access the array elements like

```
*(adjMatrix + i*numVertices + j)
```

instead of

```
adjMatrix[i][j]
```